# Bokeh; storing data into session_context or otherwise?

Tags: bokeh

I have some data that I would like to store for each user (session). I tried injecting it into `curdoc().session_context` but it appears to not be a simple data structure like a dict, it's a SessionContext object, and moreover, from reading the docs, I can't tell how to manipulate it (or it appears it is not meant to be): https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html

How can I store some arbitrary local data for each user that gets destroyed when the session is destroyed?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish. If you just need to store data between different callbacks in the same app, that can just go in module-level variables, nothing special is required. Or do you want other sessions to have access? More information about what you are trying to actually do is needed.

Comment: I want to store data between callbacks and user usage (clicking buttons etc). Right now I'm using a module imported by all sessions and indexing into a data structure by session_id, then deleting then when the session is destroyed, but it seems like there should be an easier way. Maybe an object called `session_data` that you can write into and it gets cleaned up automatically when the session is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking this, then. If you want to store data between callbacks that is contained in one session, you don't need to do anything special. You could (for example) define a module level variable `data = {}` in the Bokeh app then callbacks can read and write to the dict however you need:

```
data = {}

def button_callback(attr, old, new):
    # write some to session "data store"
    data['foo'] = 'bar'

def button_callback():
    # read some data from session "data store"
    print(data['foo'])
```

Every session will get its own instance of `data` inaccessible to any other session, that will disappear whenever the session ends.

Obviously this is fairly simplistic. A more sophisticated version might define a class with a well-defined API for storing/retrieving data, and make a module level instance of the class for callbacks to use, instead of a bare `dict`.

Comment: Does the safety of this depend on how the bokeh app is run? I'm running in Tornado embedded and added a print statement to the top of the module, and it does not seem to print on each new session.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify anything, so I assumed standard `bokeh serve` style usage with script for the app. If you are embedding Bokeh  server as a library, and using e.g. `FunctionHandler` then the "data store" object needs to be local to the function the defines the app. That is the code that is run anew every session to create new document for the session.

Answer (score 0):

With `bokeh serve` using Bokeh 2.1.1, I find that Python **instance** variables are unique to each session, so they can store session-specific data. For example, run this Bokeh app in three browser windows and click the Test button in window 1 then 2 then 3 and again in window 1 then 2 then 3 - the console messages show that each session has its own unique mySession value:

```
class InstanceVar():

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.testButton = Button(label="Test", button_type="primary")
        self.testButton.on_click(self._test)
        self.mySession = id(curdoc().session_context)
        print("Set mySession={}".format(self.mySession))

    def _test(self):
        print("mySession={}".format(self.mySession))
```

But Python **class** variables seem to be shared by all sessions; when I run the following app in the same way, all three sessions print the mySession value of the most recently started session since they are all using the same class variable in memory:

```
class ClassVar():
    mySession = None

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.testButton = Button(label="Test", button_type="primary")
        self.testButton.on_click(self._test)
        ClassVar.mySession = id(curdoc().session_context)
        print("Set mySession={}".format(ClassVar.mySession))

    def _test(self):
        print("mySession={}".format(ClassVar.mySession))
```

So I assume from this that Bokeh Server only imports each class once and therefore all sessions/users share the class variables.